# Unable To Retrieve Exact Chinese Characters in LOTus Notes IDE 8.5

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using Eclipse Integrated in Lotus Notes IDE.

I am unable to retrieve exact chineese characters for the Document or attachment name of Embedded Object.i.e., `Document.getItemValueString();` or `EmbeddedObject.getName()` instead of chineese characters i am seeing ???.

Please find below code snippet for more information.And let me know is there is away retrieve exact chineese/Russian/Korean/arbic from the document or from attachment name i.e, from EmbeddedObject.getName also please confirm whether the above mentioned issue(representing  chineese/Russian/Korean/arbic from the document or from attachment name i.e, from `EmbeddedObject.getName` ) is actually supported by Lotus Notes 8.5.

```
Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

      Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
      Document doc = db.getProfileDocument("TestForm", null);
      String str =doc.getItemValueString("filename");
System.out.println("Doc name sys"+str);

      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");

      ps.println("Doc name"+str);
```

output is

```
Doc name sys????
Doc nameä½ å¥½ä½ å¥½
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Try to printStream in a file and open the file, the System.out (I mean the console) may use a font that can't display chinese

Comment: Convert the String str to a byte array using getBytes("UTF-8"). Print the values out as hex (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).   Also do the same using getBytes() - without specifying a charset. Compare the hex strings against the values from a chart of Unicode code points. Or you can download my All Unicode Characters Database from OpenNTF and use that as your reference. http://www.openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/0/AAB7457D7B8A88F3862576CB0066F84C)

Comment: Also note that simply opening the documents in the All Unicode Characters Database is a good way of checking whether your system has the necessary fonts installed.